# Using telnet with pipe with backticks in perl

Tags: perl, pipe, telnet, backticks

I am trying to test a specific server is up and running on a certain port so I am using 
`` $result = `echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 9443`; print $result; ``

Here I am using localhost for privacy issues
The expected behavior is that it should print "...Could not open connection to the host, on port 9443: Connect failed", this way I know that the server is not running. but it prints an empty string

Any help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failure message is printed to `STDERR`, while backticks return only what goes to `STDOUT`.

You can redirect the `STDERR` stream to the `STDOUT` stream

```
$result = `echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 9443 2>&1`;
```

See [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

---

There are more rounded ways to do this, using various forms of `open`.  See [it in perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f). There are also various modules for this. The [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.44/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm) makes it rather easy.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my $cmd = 'echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 9443';

my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
  system ( $cmd );
};

print "STDOUT: $stdout";
print "STDERR: $stderr";
```

This prints for me

```
STDOUT: Trying 127.0.0.1...
STDERR: telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

The module has many more capabilities. From the docs

> Capture::Tiny provides a simple, portable way to capture almost anything sent to STDOUT or STDERR, regardless of whether it comes from Perl, from XS code or from an external program.

Comment: It still prints an empty string I've tried it. When I try other commands like `which java` it prints the output correctly, but in telnet command it doesn't

Comment: @AhmedAbuzekry  That seems strange.  I tried it and I get back the message.

Comment: I don't know I tried it before and it is not working

Comment: @AhmedAbuzekry Did you try to run `echo exit | telnet ...` on the command line?  Also, where do you do all this, what system/environment?

Comment: Yes I've tried to run it on the command line and it prints the message normally. I am using windows and trying to run this from a perl script to check for the environment before running a test.

Comment: @AhmedAbuzekry  Heh .. it should work on Windows as it stands, but it may depend on what you use for Perl. I can't test on Windows now :(  Another -- better -- option is to use a more solid tool for capturing.  For one thing, there is a well-regarded module [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.44/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm).  It is very simple to use.

Comment: @AhmedAbuzekry  I added a few links to the code, and sample code for  `Capture::Tiny`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Another possibility _might_ be `use File::Spec; my $devnull = File::Spec->devnull(); my $rc = system("echo exit | telnet 127.0.0.1 9443 1>$devnull 2>$devnull");` and then check the `$rc`. But I cannot try this out right now.